# Handle Special Format in R or others

Tags: r, database, list

I have the following data in a txt file. Note the first two lines have different columns from other lines. They must stay exactly the same so that the txt file can be fed into another software as input. The third line is data's column name and the forth line is the data. Also note ! and * have to be exactly the same as well.

```
LINES,1
TYPES,T1,I,I,N,T1
!,CODE,GROUP,MTH,COMP
*,1,16,1,"A"
```

What I need to do now is to add an extra column to the data so that it looks like below. Please note in fact there are millions of lines of data instead of just one listed here.

```
LINES,1
TYPES,T1,I,I,N,T1,I
!,CODE,GROUP,MTH,COMP,ID
*,1,16,1,"A",0
```

I tried to do so in R with the following coding.

```
line1 <- read.table("Test Case.txt", sep=",", header=FALSE, skip=0, nrows=1)
line1

line2 <- c(read.table("Test Case.txt", sep=",", header=FALSE, skip=1, nrows=1))
line2

line2 <- c(line2, "I")
line2

line3 <- read.table("Test Case.txt", sep=",", header=FALSE, skip=2)
line3

line3 <- c(line3, "ID")
line3

line4 <- read.table("Test Case.txt", sep=",", header=FALSE, skip=3)
line4

line4 <- c(line4, 0)
line4

output <- list(line1, line2, line3, line4)
output

write.table(output, "Output.txt", sep=",", col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)
```

However, the desired data structure is completely messed up in the output file. Is there a way to modify the above coding in order to achieve my goal? If R is not suitable for such endeavor, what other easily obtained language can be used instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the test data generated in the Note at the end:

```
L <- readLines("Test Case.txt")
writeLines(paste0(L, c("", ",I", ",ID", ",0")), "output.txt")
```

### Note

Set up test data:

```
Lines <- 'LINES,1
TYPES,T1,I,I,N,T1
!,CODE,GROUP,MTH,COMP
*,1,16,1,"A"
'
cat(Lines, file = "Test Case.txt")
```

Comment: Great! That does work. If there are one million lines of data, then I just need to find out ID first and then paste to {L}. Right? Is there going to be any limit on number of lines? Moreover, what does this warning mean? {Warning message: In readLines("Test Case.txt") :   incomplete final line found on 'Test Case.txt'} I forgot how to write code in comments...

Comment: The vector pasted on must have the same number of elements as lines.  If every line except the first three have a ",0" appended then we could use: `n <- length(L); v <- c("", ",I", ",ID", rep(",0", n-3)); writeLines(paste0(L, v), "output.txt")`

Comment: OK. By the way, could you remind me how to write code in comment, please?

Comment: Surround it with backticks.